# #value when using if/then and .value

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a vba function to check a cell for a name and if it matches, to return a value in another cell. As I am still new to vba, I am still hardcoding most variables to simplify things. Somehow, the simplest step in my function is letting me down.

I have tried 2 methods of writing a value to a cell, but neither works. Both return a #VALUE in Cell A2.

```
Function getRole(lastName As String, firstName as String) As String

if (lastName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = "YES"
    'Alternate method
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
    'ActiveCell.Text = "YES"
Else: 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = "NO"
    'Alternate method
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
    'ActiveCell.Text = "NO"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a **UDF** ? a function that is called from an Excel sheet ? Or this is a regular `Sub` ?

Comment: Where is the closing parentheses for the `(` before `lastname` in `if (lastName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value Then`

Comment: It is a UDF. I didn't realize that you can assign a value to a UDF directly, the answer below from Shai Rado works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to write a **UDF**, the you need to modify your code to something similar to the code below:

```
Function getRole(lastName As String, firstName As String) As String

If lastName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value Then
    getRole = "YES"
Else
    getRole = "NO"
End If

End Function
```

The way you call the **UDF** from a worksheet's cell:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code corrected for syntax:-

```
Function getRole(lastName As String, firstName as String) As String
    if lastName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = "YES"
    ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = "NO" Then
        getRole = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value 
End If End Function
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = "YES"` should be `getRole = "YES"` ?

Comment: I'm trying to show how to assign a cell value to a variable. Your answer best explains the #VALUE error the OP complains about.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
Function getRole(lastName As String, firstName As String) As String

If lastName = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value Then
    Sheet1.Range("A2") = "YES"
    'Alternate method
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
    'ActiveCell.Text = "YES"
Else
    Sheet1.Range("A2") = "NO"
    'Alternate method
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
    'ActiveCell.Text = "NO"
End If

End Function
```